# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 after installing Windows 8

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I have made a BOOTABLE USB installation of Ubuntu 13.04 using [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).
I also have Windows 8 on separate partition. After I finished installing Ubuntu 13.04 from the USB, it went straight to Windows 8 without Grub showing to ask me to select an
operating system, how can i fix this ?
I don't have UEFI or secure boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 8, try [EasyBCD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml), a handy tool that allows you to create a multiboot environment in order to run multiple operating systems on the same computer.

For me it worked.

Comment: it worked thnx , but do you have solution that doesn't require me selecting two times an operating system , like totally switching windows 8 boot manager with grub 2 ??

Comment: Now, if your grub 2 is working correctly (you have here all the help that you need to do this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), configure EasyBCD in that way to make Linux the default bootable OS and make the time for waiting equal with 0.